# XML write to relational table grouped by element

Tags: python, xml, list, hierarchical

I am facing problems rearrange the data within this XML (example and lot similar) to an array.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <bon>
    <bonnr>10010100001361599999</bonnr>
    <datum>2020-01-03T13:19:18.244+01:00</datum>
    <dynamicFieldsItem>
        <key>COUNTER</key>
        <value>5779</value>
    </dynamicFieldsItem>
    <dynamicFieldsItem>
        <key>CSNAME</key>
        <value>User Break Over 170001</value>
    </dynamicFieldsItem>
    <rskabu>
        <bulfnr>1</bulfnr>
        <buverk></buverk>
        <bupost>1</bupost>
        <buart>BRU</buart>
        <buartn>14112500</buartn>
        <buwgrp></buwgrp>
        <bumwstkz>1</bumwstkz>
        <bumwsts>7.700</bumwsts>
        <bumwstb>0.21</bumwstb>
        <dynamicFieldsItem>
            <key>ARTIKEL-LABEL</key>
            <value>grün 15</value>
        </dynamicFieldsItem>
        <dynamicFieldsItem>
            <key>CAPTURE</key>
            <value>SCAN</value>
        </dynamicFieldsItem>
        <dynamicFieldsItem>
            <key>MWSTART</key>
            <value>A</value>
        </dynamicFieldsItem>
        <dynamicFieldsItem>
            <key>MWSTKZ</key>
            <value>79</value>
        </dynamicFieldsItem>
        <dynamicFieldsItem>
            <key>W2GRP</key>
            <value>113</value>
        </dynamicFieldsItem>
    </rskabu>
    <rskabu>
        <bulfnr>2</bulfnr>
        <buverk></buverk>
        <bupost>2</bupost>
        <buart>BRU</buart>
        <buartn>14112599</buartn>
        <buwgrp></buwgrp>
        <bumwstkz>1</bumwstkz>
        <bumwsts>7.700</bumwsts>
        <bumwstb>0.21</bumwstb>
        <dynamicFieldsItem>
            <key>ARTIKEL-LABEL</key>
            <value>Glock</value>
        </dynamicFieldsItem>
        <dynamicFieldsItem>
            <key>CAPTURE</key>
            <value>SCAN</value>
        </dynamicFieldsItem>
        <dynamicFieldsItem>
            <key>MWSTART</key>
            <value>A</value>
        </dynamicFieldsItem>
    </rskabu>
    <rskab4>
        <bupost>1</bupost>
        <dynamicFieldsItem>
            <key>ZCC</key>
            <value>30.00</value>
        </dynamicFieldsItem>
        <dynamicFieldsItem>
            <key>CC</key>
            <value>OFF</value>
        </dynamicFieldsItem>
    </rskab4>
    <rskdwp>
        <dwlfnr>1</dwlfnr>
        <dwrow>0</dwrow>
        <dwcol>0</dwcol>
        <dwcpi>-1</dwcpi>
        <dwcmd>28</dwcmd>
        <dwtext>CUE</dwtext>
    </rskdwp>
    <rskdwp>
        <dwlfnr>2</dwlfnr>
        <dwrow>0</dwrow>
        <dwcol>0</dwcol>
        <dwcpi>-1</dwcpi>
        <dwcmd>28</dwcmd>
        <dwtext>END</dwtext>
    </rskdwp> </bon>
```

I thought I write the data to different tables like I show in the lists below.
Then it would be easy to insert the data to the database.

```
BON
---
bonnr,datum
10010100001361599999,2020-01-03T13:19:18.244+01:00

BON_DYNAMIC
-----------
bonnr,datum,key,value
10010100001361599999,2020-01-03T13:19:18.244+01:00,COUNTER,5779
10010100001361599999,2020-01-03T13:19:18.244+01:00,CSNAME,User Break Over 170001

BON_RSKABU
----------
bonnr,datum,bulfnr,buverk,bupost,buart,buartn,buwgrp,bumwstkz,bumwsts,bumwstb
10010100001361599999,2020-01-03T13:19:18.244+01:00,1,,1,BRU,14112500,,,1,7.700,0.21
10010100001361599999,2020-01-03T13:19:18.244+01:00,2,,2,BRU,14112599,,,1,7.700,0.21

BON_RSKABU_DYN
--------------
bonnr,datum,bulfnr,key,value
10010100001361599999,2020-01-03T13:19:18.244+01:00,1,ARTIKEL-LABEL,grün 15
10010100001361599999,2020-01-03T13:19:18.244+01:00,1,CAPTURE,SCAN
10010100001361599999,2020-01-03T13:19:18.244+01:00,1,MWSTART,A
10010100001361599999,2020-01-03T13:19:18.244+01:00,1,MWSTKZ,79
10010100001361599999,2020-01-03T13:19:18.244+01:00,1,W2GRP,113
10010100001361599999,2020-01-03T13:19:18.244+01:00,2,ARTIKEL-LABEL,Glock
10010100001361599999,2020-01-03T13:19:18.244+01:00,2,CAPTURE,SCAN
10010100001361599999,2020-01-03T13:19:18.244+01:00,2,MWSTART,A

BON_RSKAB4
----------
bonnr,datum,bupost,key,value
10010100001361599999,2020-01-03T13:19:18.244+01:00,1,ZCC,30.00
10010100001361599999,2020-01-03T13:19:18.244+01:00,1,CC.OFF

BON_RSKDWP
----------
bonnr,datum,dwlfnr,dwrow,dwcol,dwcpi,dwcmd,dwtext
10010100001361599999,2020-01-03T13:19:18.244+01:00,1,0,0,-1,28,CUE
10010100001361599999,2020-01-03T13:19:18.244+01:00,1,0,0,-1,28,END
```

The problem is mainly with the grouping attributes from different branches.
First I spend some time to try to dictify the data, which would work for very simple
kind of XML.
If one could show me an Python example how to do it for an example like BON_RSKABU or BON_RSKABU_DYN I would be very happy.The problems is to select the data from different hierarchie levels and have the data populated even it occurs just once.

Answer (score 2):

In python, you can do it with lxml, using xpath and pandas. I'll explain as we go along. We'll take your `BON_RSKABU` as an example:

```
import lxml.html
import pandas as pd

bonn = """[your html above]""" #you may need to delete your top encoding delclaration (<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> )
root = etree.fromstring(bonn) #parse the html

columns = [] #initialize lists for collecting the headers and the table rows
rows = []
bonn = root.xpath('.//bonnr')#locate header 1
dats = root.xpath('.//datum')#locate header 2
rsks = root.xpath('//rskabu') #locate the data itself
columns.append(bonn[0].tag) #add the 1st and 2nd column items to the columns list
columns.append(dats[0].tag)
for head in rsks[0][:9]: #you are only interested in the first 9 items, so append their names to the column list as well
    columns.append(head.tag)

for rsk in rsks: #now collect the data for each row
    row=[]
    row.append(bonn[0].text) #add the first 2 standalone data items to your row
    row.append(dats[0].text)
    item = rsk.xpath('.//*') #locate the rest of the data
    for i in item[:9]:  #now add the rest of the data (but only the first 9) to your row
        row.append(i.text)        
    rows.append(row) #add this row to the final rows list

df = pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=columns) #now create a pandas dataframe to house all this
df
```

Output (sorry about the formatting):

> bonnr datum bulfnr buverk bupost buart buartn buwgrp bumwstkz bumwsts bumwstb 
>    10010100001361599999 2020-01-03T13:19:18.244+01:00 1 None 1
>   BRU 14112500 None 
>   7.700
>   0.21  10010100001361599999 2020-01-03T13:19:18.244+01:00 2 None 2 BRU 14112599 None 
>   7.700
>   0.21

Comment: This is really a comfortable solution. Thank you that help me a lot. I have to try whether it can cope with missing elements.

Comment: I checked that in some file there are multiple <bon>-Elements. As well there are sometimes some elements missing. Like for rskabu there are sometimes the elements bumwstkz,bumwsts,bumwstb missing. It is the same for the other elements, sometimes the elements with no content are missing.

I think I can just iterate through the xml tree and put together my records.

Comment: @Manfred - Correct, the code in the answer doesn't deal with multiple `<bon>` elements or missing elements like `<bumwsts>`. But it should not be too difficult to add some `for` loops before and inside the code, I believe.

Comment: How can I find an element from the XPath result by tag name?
If I just evaluate each elent in the loop I can not do anything with missing elements.
I think then it is better if I get all elements back I need for my result:
xml.xpath('/bon/*[not(self::dynamicFieldsItem)]')

Comment: @Manfred - Not sure what you mean. I suggest you create a new question with a much more simplified xml which has missing elements or any other structural problem, and the desire output. Let me know when it's posted and I'll take a look. SO doesn't like extended discussions in comments...